# Responsive web page - splash page

Tags: html, responsive-design

I know this is a basic question but I'm having difficultly making my site responsive.

It is a basic page that I've done in Photoshop. I've tried a lot of things to make it responsive with no luck.

Here is my HTML code:

```
<html>
<head>
<title>newbeebosite</title>
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8">
</head>
<body bgcolor="#FFFFFF" leftmargin="0" topmargin="0" marginwidth="0" marginheight="0">
<!-- Save for Web Slices (newbeebosite.psd) -->
<table id="Table_01" width="1601" height="1401" border="0" cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0">
    <tr>
        <td colspan="7">
            <img src="images/Home_01.jpg" width="1600" height="21" alt=""></td>
        <td>
            <img src="images/spacer.gif" width="1" height="21" alt=""></td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td colspan="5" rowspan="2">
            <img src="images/Home_02.jpg" width="1216" height="46" alt=""></td>
        <td>
            <img src="images/Home_03.jpg" width="192" height="45" alt=""></td>
        <td>
            <img src="images/Home_04.jpg" width="192" height="45" alt=""></td>
        <td>
            <img src="images/spacer.gif" width="1" height="45" alt=""></td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td colspan="2" rowspan="2">
            <img src="images/Home_05.jpg" width="384" height="88" alt=""></td>
        <td>
            <img src="images/spacer.gif" width="1" height="1" alt=""></td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td>
            <img src="images/Home_06.jpg" width="78" height="87" alt=""></td>
        <td>
            <img src="images/Home_07.jpg" width="251" height="87" alt=""></td>
        <td colspan="3">
            <img src="images/Home_08.jpg" width="887" height="87" alt=""></td>
        <td>
            <img src="images/spacer.gif" width="1" height="87" alt=""></td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td colspan="3">
            <img src="images/Home_09.jpg" width="971" height="160" alt=""></td>
        <td>
            <img src="images/Home_10.jpg" width="1" height="160" alt=""></td>
        <td colspan="2">
            <img src="images/Home_11.jpg" width="436" height="160" alt=""></td>
        <td>
            <img src="images/Home_12.jpg" width="192" height="160" alt=""></td>
        <td>
            <img src="images/spacer.gif" width="1" height="160" alt=""></td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td colspan="7">
            <img src="images/Home_13.jpg" width="1600" height="1086" alt=""></td>
        <td>
            <img src="images/spacer.gif" width="1" height="1086" alt=""></td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td>
            <img src="images/spacer.gif" width="78" height="1" alt=""></td>
        <td>
            <img src="images/spacer.gif" width="251" height="1" alt=""></td>
        <td>
            <img src="images/spacer.gif" width="642" height="1" alt=""></td>
        <td>
            <img src="images/spacer.gif" width="1" height="1" alt=""></td>
        <td>
            <img src="images/spacer.gif" width="244" height="1" alt=""></td>
        <td>
            <img src="images/spacer.gif" width="192" height="1" alt=""></td>
        <td>
            <img src="images/spacer.gif" width="192" height="1" alt=""></td>
        <td></td>
    </tr>
</table>
<!-- End Save for Web Slices -->
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As a starter I would add:

```html
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
```

in the head of your html document.

#### Explanation

This tells the browsers CSS engine "use the screen width of the device (measured in "device independent pixels") as the basis for your HTML element" - and therefore all "fluidly styled" descendant (child) elements will be affected because their height and width properties are based on their parent elements size.

`width=device-width` is what instructs the page to match the screen's width in device independent pixels. (as opposed to say `width=1024` which would explicitly set the width of the page.)

Now when the browser width changes your CSS rules will be hooked into those changes.
I believe `initial-scale=1` establishs a 1:1 relationship between CSS pixels and device independent pixels (If that doesnt make sense dont worry - but I would include it).

Then you need to make the table responsive by removing the fixed width definitions and replacing with width definition that change as the parent containers change size.

There is a good explanation of this here - https://developers.google.com/speed/docs/insights/ConfigureViewport

e.g. like this:

```
<body bgcolor="#FFFFFF" leftmargin="0" topmargin="0" marginwidth="0" marginheight="0">
<!-- Save for Web Slices (newbeebosite.psd) -->
<table id="Table_01"  border="0" cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0">
    <tr>
        <td colspan="7">
            <img src="http://lorempixel.com/400/200/" width="80%" height="21" alt=""></td>
        <td>
            <img src="http://lorempixel.com/400/200/" width="80%" height="21" alt=""></td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td colspan="5" rowspan="2">
            <img src="http://lorempixel.com/400/200/" width="80%" height="46" alt=""></td>
        <td>
            <img src="http://lorempixel.com/400/200/" width="80%" height="45" alt=""></td>
        <td>
            <img src="http://lorempixel.com/400/200/" width="80%" height="45" alt=""></td>
        <td>
            <img src="http://lorempixel.com/400/200/" width="80%" height="45" alt=""></td>
    </tr>

</table>
<!-- End Save for Web Slices -->
</body>
```

Here is a working **demo** - http://jsbin.com/dilejobofu/1/edit?html,output

Comment: Thanks Michael for your help; much appreciated. Will give this a go. Noticed already the <meta name> has helped. Now it's just about scaling the images correctly.

Comment: No problem, If you found the answer useful , you can select by clicking the big tick